# C program assign index and sort

Tags: sorting, indexing, assign

I am trying to create a C program which gets input from keyboard and assigns index number to each input beginning from 0. Example if input is 2,3,4,5,6,7,6 the index will be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. Then I need to sort the inputs and accordingly the index should be sorted too. After that I need to remove duplicates from the inputs and re sort them according to the index this time.

Comment: please add some source-code!

Comment: int first_value; //First value to determine how many numbers will be entered
 int *num_list=(int*)malloc(first_value*sizeof(int));
 int index[first_value];
 printf("Start entering numbers");
 scanf("%d",&first_value);

 for(int i=0;i<first_value;i++)
 {
  scanf("%d",&num_list[i]);
  index[i]=i;
 }
   printf("\n");
 qsort(num_list,first_value,sizeof(int),comparisonFunction);

 printf("\n");
 for(int j=0;j<first_value;j++)
 {
  printf("%d\n",num_list[j]);
 }

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. I do not know how to paste the code to look like on editor.

Comment: An alternative would be to create an array of pointers, and assign a pointer to each input, then sort the pointers according to the values they point to, possibly by using qsort (note qsort will pass a pair of pointer to pointer to value to the caller's compare routine). This eliminates the need for the compare function to know the name of the array of inputs. A pointer can be converted into an index by subtracting a pointer to the first element of the array from the current pointer.

Comment: @rcgldr I understood what you said very clearly. But I have trouble putting it in code. How would you assign individual pointers to array of pointers.  Thank you very much

Comment: @TufanAcharya - in a loop, `arrayofpointers[i] = arrayofintegers+i;` or `arrayofpointers[i] = &arrayofintegers[i];` . To convert to index: `index = arrayofpointers[i] - arrayofintegers`  or  `index = arrayofpointers[i] - &arrayofintegers[0]` .

Comment: @TufanAcharya you can edit your original post and thereby refine your question